# When a user updates their profile picture on my Spring web app and updates their profile, objects in a list belonging to the user are duplicated

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am developing a web app with Spring.

This web app is a music sharing platform. With it a user can register and make a profile and can write posts or upload tracks. I have a user model with various attributes such as List and a track model. A user has a List of tracks (List) and when they upload a track it is added to this list.

One feature I want to have is for a user to upload a profile picture and I have created methods that allow this. However, when a user uploads this picture every track in the users list gets duplicated multiple times. So for example, if a user has a list containing 3 tracks called A, B, C, when they upload a profile picture their list might contain A, A, A, B, B, B, C, C, C or some other number of duplications. Furthermore, every time that user adds a new unrelated post the list will continue to duplicate. This will always happen after the profile picture has been uploaded, but not before.

Below is my method in the controller. This calls the uploadPic method and passes it the file and current user.

```
@RequestMapping(value="profilepic", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addProfilePic(@RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file, Model model, Principal principal) {

        String name = principal.getName(); 
        User u = userService.findByUsername(name);

        this.amazonClient.uploadPic(file, u);

        return "redirect:/settings?bio_success";
    }
```

This method saves the picture to an AWS S3 bucket and then calls a service method.

```
public String uploadPic(MultipartFile multipartFile, User u) {
    String fileUrl = "";
    try {
        File file = convertMultiPartToFile(multipartFile);
        String fileName = generateFileName(multipartFile);
        System.out.println(fileName);
        fileUrl = endpointUrl + "/" + picBucketName + "/" + fileName;
        uploadPicTos3bucket(fileName, file);
        file.delete();       
        picService.save(u, fileName);

    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fileUrl;
}
```

The service method saves the picture in a MySQL table and calls a method to update the user.
AmazonClient.java

```
@Override
public void save(User u, String fileName) {
    ProfilePic newPic = new ProfilePic();
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    newPic.setFileName(fileName);
    newPic.setPublishTime(timestamp);
    newPic.setUser(u);
    profilePicRepository.save(newPic);  
    u.setProfilePic(newPic);
    userService.update(u);
}
```

UserService.java

```
@Override
public void update(User user) {
    user.setPassword(user.getPassword());
    user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(roleRepository.findAll()));
    user.setFname(user.getFname());
    user.setLname(user.getLname());
    user.setFriends(user.getFriends());
    user.setIncomingFriendRequests(user.getIncomingFriendRequests());
    user.setOutgoingFriendRequests(user.getOutgoingFriendRequests());
    user.setProfilePic(user.getProfilePic());
    user.setComments(user.getComments());
    user.setPost(user.getPost());
    user.setTracks(user.getTracks());
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

I have other features where a user can update their details similar to this but this problem does not occur and only happens with the uploading of a profile picture.

When I debug and step through every method the user is updated seems to update correctly, including the number of tracks.

I created the below little script to try find the problem and the output of this script is below. Maybe this will help get an idea of what is causing this.

```
        String name = principal.getName(); 
        User u = userService.findByUsername(name);


        this.amazonClient.uploadPic(file, u);
        for (Track t : u.getTracks()) {
            System.out.println(t.getTrackName());
        }

        User user2 = userService.findByUsername(name);
        for (Track t : user2.getTracks()) {
            System.out.println(t.getTrackName());
        }
```

**Output:** Liberate
In the reds
Pjanoo

Liberate
Liberate
Liberate
Liberate
Liberate
Liberate
Liberate
Liberate
Liberate
In the reds
In the reds
In the reds
In the reds
In the reds
In the reds
In the reds
In the reds
In the reds
Pjanoo
Pjanoo
Pjanoo
Pjanoo
Pjanoo
Pjanoo
Pjanoo
Pjanoo
Pjanoo

Should the output not be the same for both since I am finding the same User as usernames are unique?
Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happening on the frontend? Did upload form do some dupe send to the server?

Comment: update(User user): the User entity have unical ID in his description? Check ID there.

Comment: User has auto generated unique id, in my test script above both users have same id

Comment: I have changed the List<Track> in the user entity to Set<Track> and it seems to have fixed the issue! thanks anyway for trying to help me, appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the List in the user entity to Set and it seems to have fixed the issue as sets cannot have duplicates!